# Disable keyboard on text selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection

I have an application that uses both Android's default keyboard and my custom keyboard. I already set it that whenever the default keyboard is called, my custom keyboard is closed and vice versa. My problem is, on some devices like Galaxy S3, whenever a text is selected, the default keyboard is shown overlapping my custom keyboard. **Is there a way to handle or modify the event for selecting/highlighting text on an edittext?**

Answer (score 0):

> Try this my work for u

```
Keypad.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Tried that. Also tried adding statealwayshidden in Manifest, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

using event ::

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
 && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() 
 || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
 return ret;
}
```

Comment: My problem is to add that function on the event when the user is selecting/highlighting a text.